# When sending udp it returns EMSGSIZE error but the packet doesn't exceed PMTU or UDP limit

Tags: c++, kubernetes, udp

I wrote the following C++ codes to send udp packets (error handling is omitted here):

```cpp
int fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP);
int rc = setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (void*)&a, 4);
sockaddr_in *addr = new sockaddr_in;
bzero(addr, sizeof(addr));
addr->sin_family=AF_INET;
addr->sin_port=htons(4756);
addr->sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("10.157.75.99");
rc = connect(fd, (struct sockaddr*)addr, 16);
char buf[1600];
   for (int i = 0; i < 1600; i++)
      buf[i] = 0;
   srand((unsigned)time( NULL ) );
   for (int j = 0; j<100000; j++)
   {
      usleep(20000);
      int nn = rand()%1500;
      std::cout<<"the original bytes is "<<nn+100<<std::endl;
      rc = write(fd, (void*)buf, 100+nn);
      std::cout<<"sent bytes is"<<rc<<std::endl;
      if (rc < 0)
      {
         std::cout<<errno<<std::endl;
         if (errno == 90)   //EMSGSIZE
            std::cout<<"message too long"<<std::endl;
      }
      //std::cout<<rc<<std::endl;
      int mtusize = 0;
      socklen_t len1 = sizeof(mtusize);

      int rc2 = getsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IP,IP_MTU,&mtusize,&len1);
      if(rc2 == 0)
      {
         std::cout<<"get pmtu successful"<<std::endl;
         std::cout<<"pmtu size is: "<<mtusize<<std::endl;
      }
      ...
```

I called write function for 100000 times and the payload size is between 100 bytes and 1600 bytes.  Sometimes I got EMSGSIZE(90) errno (around 4 times). The output is as follow (the pmtu discovery is always on):

```
the original bytes is 143
sent bytes is-1
90
message too long
get pmtu successful
pmtu size is: 1500
```

From the output, the PMTU obtained by getsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IP,IP_MTU,&mtusize,&len1) is always 1500 bytes.
The question is: sometimes when calling the following system call:

```cpp
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

The third argument (count) is far less than 1500 bytes (143 bytes in the example above), but why did the errno 90 (message too long) return?
And sometimes, the count is more than 1500 bytes, but write returns 0(success).

Btw, the "message too long" error only occurs when I run the program in K8s pod. When I run it on the node, there is no such error (the PMTU is also 1500 bytes on the node).

Updates:

I found that the PMTU is not always 1500. At the beginning, the PMTU is 2120, and when sending a packet that is larger than 1500, the PMTU dropped to 1500:

```
begin to write
the original bytes is 545
get pmtu successful
pmtu size is: 2120
get pmtu disc successful
pmtu disc is: 1
begin to write
the original bytes is 1565
get pmtu successful
pmtu size is: 1500
get pmtu disc successful
pmtu disc is: 1
begin to write
the original bytes is 744
message too long
get pmtu successful
pmtu size is: 1500
```

And after that, the next packet to be sent will trigger the "message too long" error.
2120 is the local MTU and 1500 is the path MTU.
However it is still unknown why the write of the packet that is larger than  1500 will succeed while the next packet will catch the "message too long" error even if its size is smaller than 1500.

Comment: You never check if `socket`, `setsockopt` or `connect` fails. Also, what is `a` and what is its value? And why do you use the [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) `90` instead of the proper symbolic constant `EMSGSIZE` to check? Or just use `strerror(errno)` to get a printable string of the actual error.

Comment: You shouldn't call any function, including printing, between discovering an error and checking `errno`.

Comment: The MTU defines max size of the transmission unit. It includes Ethernet header (14 bytes) + IP Header (min 20 bytes) + UDP Header (8 bytes). So if MTU == 1500, max payload size is 1458 bytes, but can be less - depends on the IP header size.

Comment: I've never sent messages larger than MTU, did you check what do you receive on the remote side? Does Kernel split large UDP messages?